# jquery convert timestamp from getJSON

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to get data json schedule flight and the data json content  timestamp of flight schedule and am trying to convert to local time

my code :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON("v1/airport.json?code=bgw", function(data) {

    $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function() {
      var d = new Date("<p>" + this.flight.time.scheduled.arrival + "</p>" * 1000)


      $("#id").append("<p>" + this.flight.identification.number.default+"</p>");


      if (this.flight.airport.origin) {
        $("#city").append("<p>" + this.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city + "</p>");
      }

    });

  });

});
```

I try with this code to get time flight but it is not working

```
var d = new Date("<p>" + this.flight.time.scheduled.arrival + "</p>" * 1000)
```

[**my data json link**](http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/?id=08ce07c07754ce6ccf5c4caf39f8ac92)

Comment: Why are you putting `<p>` tags in your `Date()`? While I don't know the contents of `this.flight.time.scheduled.arrival`, I can assure you that inside the `Date()`, you do not want it wrapped in `<p>` tags. Your `var d` is likely just returning `Invalid Date`.

Comment: Not to mention multiplying a `<p>` tag by 1000...

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Santi i put the link for data json , you check `this.flight.time.scheduled.`

Comment: `<p>` is not part of a date, regardless of what the scheduled time is. Try removing them from the `Date()`.

Comment: Your code works if you remove the P from the new date: https://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/gycLounb/

Answer (score 0):

work fine :)

```
 $ (document).ready (function(){
        $.getJSON("/v1/airport.json?code=bgw", function(data){

        $.each(data.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data, function(){
    var d = new Date(this.flight.time.scheduled.arrival * 1000)


          $("#id").append("<p>"+this.flight.identification.number.default+"</p>");
          $("#time").append("<p>"+d+"</p>");


          if (this.flight.airport.origin) {
            $("#city").append("<p>"+this.flight.airport.origin.position.region.city+"</p>");
          } 

        });

        });

    });
```